# Vue content rendering outside parent component

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

When I load a vue component inside a @foreach tag it gets rendered first, outside of its parent component.

```
 //view 
     <div class="contenido" style="padding-top:5%">

         <table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-md-8">Nombre descripción general</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2">Actualizar</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2">Consultar</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($descs as $desc)
                        <tab-descgen desc-nombre = "{{ $desc -> nombre }}" desc-id = "{{ $desc -> id }}"></tab-descgen>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>

            </table>

   //vue component
   <template>
    <tr >
         <td>{{ this.descNombre }}</td>
     <td><i style="font-size:30px;" class="fa fa-edit float-center"></i> 
 </td>
     <td><i style="font-size:30px;" class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right 
   float-center"></i></td>
  </tr>
   </template>

  <script>
    export default {
       props:['descNombre', 'descId'],
```

When this gets rendered the table rows inside the vue component will be rendered above the header, and I don't quite understand why. I want to know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even ignoring all the server-side stuff, this won't work:

```html
<tbody>
  <tab-descgen></tab-descgen>
</tbody>
```

It'd be fine in a single-file component but if this markup makes it to the browser (as it will in your case) it'll rip the `tab-descgen` out of the table before Vue gets anywhere near it.

You'd need to use `is` to work around it:

```html
<tbody>
  <tr is="tab-descgen"></tr>
</tbody>
```

It's explained here in the docs:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats

In short, only `tr` elements are allowed as direct children of `tbody`, anything else gets pulled out. The workaround is to use a `tr` and then let Vue know what you really wanted using `is`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know, your workaround worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Its because that content is rendered before Vue loads, i.e. Blade(php) renders the content -> Loads any Javascript(Vue) -> Vue renders

Comment: I thought it had something to do with it, do you know how to work around it? or should I just have my entire table in the vue component?

Comment: You have a couple of options. My preference is to have Vue handle everything including fetching the data.

Comment: Already tried that, issue is if you do it like that I can't figure out how to use the laravel paginate function with it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on which paginate function you are not able to use?

Comment: In my controller I'm returning a view with a variable that has paginated data. if I pass that variable to the vue component as a prop and then use v-for to loop it the table breaks, should i try to fetch the data from the url or something?

Comment: if you inspect the `variable that has paginated data` you will see that the variable should have a property similar to `data` along with other pagination details. Instead of passing the entire variable to the vue component as a prop, you should instead pass the property. `$desc->data` - you will need to inspect the variable to find the property name/key - try a `dd($desc)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass all the data to the Vue component and do the loop in there.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that, the sad part is that if I do that I can't use the integrated "paginate" function within laravel.

Comment: Yes, you can. Just pull the data from the paginator. Post some more code so we can help you.